# ASP.NET with IIS url rewrite on language change

Tags: c#, redirect, iis, url-rewriting, translation

I have imprelemnted a complex url rewrite to translate user frendly url into internal application url.

So basically if you go to my site (an ecommerce) :
"https://some_domain/en/shoes/some_brand/article-description-written-in-a-firendly-manner_articleCode"

Then the url is rewritten into the internal version "https://some_domain/Products.aspx?id=articleCode&languageCode=en"

The viceversa also is true, when an internal URL need to be produced and placed into the page, it's rewritten into it's "external" shape.

Everything work just fine, until someone will change the language (eg : from 'en' to 'de').
Language change like many other parameter change is applied on query string, so changing language will trigger a page refresh with the trailing parameter into query string.

So 'en' to 'de' in the previous url will casue the following call :
"https://some_domain/en/shoes/some_brand/article-description-written-in-a-firendly-manner_articleCode?languageCode=de"

Then even if server-side i consider the language to be german, how i can rewrite the url displaied into the browser?

It should become something similar to :
"https://some_domain/de/schuhe/some_brand/artikelbeschreibung-freundlich-geschrieben_articleCode"

Should i calculate the new external URL and do a 302 redirect (HttpResponse.Redirect)?
Or is a better option put the precalculated url as link in the language change button?

Comment: Did you want to redirect from `https://some_domain/en/shoes/some_brand/article-description-written-in-a-firendly-manner_articleCode?languageCode=de` to `https://some_domain/de/schuhe/some_brand/artikelbeschreibung-freundlich-geschrieben_articleCode`? or you want to change the language of the url when redirecting? can you give an example?

Comment: I have the english version page opened (/en/shoes/..) and some buttons with flag to switch language (remaining into the same page). My old logic only change url prameter and then reload. So page know (server-side) that the content should be localized in english. But now i need to localize also the url, and i can't change it when i recive the post with the udpated parameter. So my first guess is to use a 302 redirect, but meanwhile i opted to forge the current page url in many localization inside the button href. This solution seems to work, but i don't know if optimal

Comment: So if before i have `https://s_d/myPage.aspx?languageCode=en` -> `https://s_d/myPage.aspx?languageCode=de` now with the url rewrite i have the page body with many anchor (one foreach language button) in which serverside i build the current page url localized in the specific language (for each language). Flag button click isn't anymore a simple querystring parameter change and then page reload, but is a navigation to a very different url. That way i reach my goal without redirect.